# Existential goals are filled in too soon

Tags: record, coq, typeclass, coq-tactic

I have a `Class` containing both data and axioms. I want to build another instance in proof mode, based on (1) an existing instance and (2) some other input. I want to `destruct` this second input before creating the new instance of the record.

The minimal `Class` that works as an example is shrunk from one in [jwiegley/category-theory](https://github.com/jwiegley/category-theory):

```
Require Import Coq.Unicode.Utf8.
Require Import Coq.Init.Datatypes.
Require Import Coq.Classes.Morphisms.
Require Import Coq.Classes.SetoidDec.

Generalizable All Variables.

Reserved Infix "~>" (at level 90, right associativity).
Reserved Infix "∘" (at level 40, left associativity).

Record Category := {
  obj : Type;

  uhom := Type : Type;
  hom : obj -> obj -> uhom where "a ~> b" := (hom a b);
  homset :> ∀ X Y, Setoid (X ~> Y);

  compose {x y z} (f: y ~> z) (g : x ~> y) : x ~> z
    where "f ∘ g" := (compose f g);

  compose_respects x y z :>
    Proper (equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) (@compose x y z);
}.
```

Suppose (2) is `bool`:

```
Definition newCat (C : Category) (b : bool) : Category.
Proof.
  destruct b.
  - eapply Build_Category.
    Unshelve.
```

At this point, `obj` is filled in with `Type`:

```
  C : Category
  ============================
  ∀ x y z : Type, Proper (equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) (?compose x y z)

subgoal 2 (ID 18) is:
 ∀ x y z : Type, (λ _ A : Type, A) y z → (λ _ A : Type, A) x y → (λ _ A : Type, A) x z
```

This behavior disappears if I remove the `compose_respects` axiom (or use some other kind of `Record` without such a field). If I change `Category` into a `Class`, `obj` will be filled in as the `obj` of `C`. It seems to have something to do with typeclass resolution (the fact that the `equiv`s have implicit typeclass arguments?).

Is there someway to prevent these (or any!) variables from being filled in with unification? The optimal result would be something like `eapply`+`Unshelve` where no existentials are generated at all, and I can fill in the record's fields as subgoals, in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `simple notypeclasses refine {| obj := _ |}` does the trick.

- `{| obj := _|}` is record syntax that functions as shorthand for `Build_Category _ _ _ _ _`.
- `simple notypeclasses refine` is all one tactic. It's a variant of `notypeclasses refine` that doesn't shelve goals and performs no reduction.
- Sadly there isn't a generic `notypeclasses` combinator, unlike `unshelve`. There's just `notypeclasses refine` and `simple notypeclasses refine`.

For debugging, you can use the (undocumented) `Set Typeclasses Debug`. This reveals that `eapply Build_Category` does resolve some typeclasses, and `refine {| obj := _|}` is even worse.

As an aside, I don't think it makes sense to have `Class Category` without any type-level parameters - why would you ever want just any category automatically inferred?

Comment: I agree, but that's the way the library is written :) Thanks for all the tips, those are all very helpful.

Comment: Oh I see, didn't realize your use of a Record was a change from the library. I'm still not sure why it would be a Class, but I'm not super familiar with typeclasses in Coq.